# Make 10,000 random integer tuples quickly

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7

I'm doing a dumb little challenge I got from one of my co-workers;

> Make 10,000 random integer tuples, in the same format as a RSA token, in under 30 seconds.

I've successfully done the 10,000 in under 30 seconds but want to know if there's a way to speed this program up a little bit? As of now it averages at about `21.205666701` seconds. From three different runs:

- `On request number: 10000. Done! That took: 19.5520000458 seconds`
- `On request number: 10000. Done! That took: 23.8059999943 seconds`
- `On request number: 10000. Done! That took: 20.2590000629 seconds`

How can I refactor this script and speed up the process time, if I am able to?

```
import time
import sys
from random import randint


def create_integer_tuple():
    return randint(100, 999), randint(100, 999)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    strt_time = time.time()
    times_done = 0
    while True:
        with open("challenge_accepted.txt", "a+") as data:
            if times_done != 10000:
                data.write(str(create_integer_tuple()) + "\n")
                times_done += 1
                sys.stdout.write("\rOn request number: {}.".format(times_done))
                sys.stdout.flush()
            else:
                print(" Done! That took: {} seconds".format(time.time() - strt_time))
                break
```

Comment: What is the range of these numbers, and could the number be repeated?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com 

Try here to improve your working code.

Comment: Use `timeit` to time your functions

Comment: @MooingRawr will do, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Don't print something on each iteration to stdout (down to 2 seconds)
2. Move `with open("challenge_accepted.txt", "a+") as data:` outside of the loop. Why would you always close and reopen the file? (down to 0.06 seconds (with 1.))

Answer (score 3):

I've got the world's worst computer and your program took 1.5 seconds. What are you using... a rock and a stick? (smile). I took out the print to screen which cut it down to .625. Then I replaced the `while` with a `for`. All you were really doing with the `times_done` comparison was reimplementing a for loop inefficiently. That got me to .132. Finally, I removed the function call and inlined the random tuple creation and got down to .130.

```
import time
import sys
from random import randint

if __name__ == '__main__':
    strt_time = time.time()
    with open("challenge_accepted.txt", "a+") as data:
        for times_done in range(10000):
            data.write(str((randint(100,999), randint(100, 999))) + "\n")
    print(" Done! That took: {} seconds".format(time.time() - strt_time))
```

Now time for the radical surgery. I'm still making a lot of `data.write` calls and referencing intermediate variables I really don't need. `writelines` takes an iterator, so lets use it.

```
import time
import sys
from random import randint

if __name__ == '__main__':
    strt_time = time.time()
    with open("challenge_accepted.txt", "a+") as data:
        data.writelines(
            str((randint(100,999), randint(100, 999))) + "\n"
            for _ in range(10000))
    print(" Done! That took: {} seconds".format(time.time() - strt_time))
```

I got .111 seconds.

Comment: If you execute in IDLE instead of command line it takes much longer, I guess

Comment: It takes a lot longer then yours @yassin but a lot less time then mine

Comment: @Pyth0nicPenguin on my system his version is a little bit faster ;)

Comment: @Pyth0nicPenguin Yeah, I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

```
[get_rnd_tuple() for x in xrange(10000)]
```

you dont need if statements or branching ... this should be a little faster